# Fabric not working if not initialised in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Tags: ios, google-analytics, twitter-fabric, fabric.io, google-fabric

We have integrated Fabric in our application. We observed that dashboard is not updating if we initialise fabric object other than didFinishLaunch.. I should not initialise in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions because before initialising I have to show OptIn page for the user. So nn his acceptance only I should initiate the Fabric..  Can you help me in this?

Following is the code I added for initialising.

```
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug:YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

Comment: what issues your are faced ?

Comment: Its clearly methion [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) to initilize it in the DidFinishLaunching. So why you do not wanna do that ?

Comment: "other than didFinishLaunch" Where exactly ?

Comment: I have to show Fabric OptIn page for the user.. On his acceptance only I should initiate the Fabric.. @UmairAfzal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Fabric support, it seems their logic is completely based on app life cycle and it work properly if we initialise the Faric object other than didFinishLauch method..

So we ended up changing the logic in my app.. We are initialising Fabric for first time even if user not yet accepted in OptIn page, but not logging any custom events if he not opted-in. And then from the second launch it works as per his decision on OptIn page.

Thanks all for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in didFinishLaunching:

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

it's may be help you..

Comment: Yes this works fine but I need to keep this in some other viewController.. If I do so it does not work.

Comment: this code for whole app so you can use for one time not required to write in  all classes.

Comment: Yeah.. I have updated the que. Please check it so that you can have better understanding of my issue.

Comment: you need to install fabric app on your system then your dashboard is  updating.